# Is File Reference for Deserialization acceptable in a database?

Tags: c#, xml, database-design, fluent-nhibernate, xml-serialization

I have a situation where I need to store some data that just won't ...really fit into a database table. It is a little too abstract, and I've not enough knowledge to piecemeal it in such a way that it could be broken into tables and columns. The object in question is a `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<T>`.

I have discovered a means of serializing such to xml using `MetaLinq`. and it works pretty well, albeit the xml it generates is excessively obese, I somewhat expected this much from something as complicated as an Expression. A modest expression turns out to around 19 kb.

So my thought was to use gzip compression on the file. This works well, it saves it to about 2 kb.

So then, my actual question is this : is it bad practice or 'dangerous' practice to basically use a table column to reference a filename for deserialization for an object? Like I would have a table for expressions, and it would have a filename, when that expression was called it would perform the gzip decompression, deserialize it, and return the object.

This seems like the ideal solution but it requires a lot of File I/O and a lot of various compression/zipping/serialization. I'm wondering if I could get the opinion of more experienced database admins out there. I am using `Fluent nHibernate` as my ORM mapper.

[MetaLinq on codeplex](http://metalinq.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Oracle actually allows one to reference a external file in a table through the [BFILE Data Type](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_bfile_external_lob.htm). AFAIK SQL Server does not implement this; but you should notice that is perfectly possible to store XML data into a table through the [XML Data Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx).

Comment: @rsenna: Thankfully, since SQL Server 2008, MSSQL provides a system like Oracle's BFILE data type. In MSSQL's case, it's done through a [FILESTREAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc949109.aspx). The best part is, you can access it through T-SQL or directly via SMB **and** it will get backed up when you back up the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the size of the data.

Sql has an XML data type for table columns now.  So you could deserialize the object and then insert the whole object in the column again depending on size.

But if you must use the file system I would store a path and the file name in the column.
In your programs app.config keep the root of the drive like \\MyDrive or d:\

That way if information moves, just change the app config as long as the folder/file structure stays the same.

**Edit:**
Along with NerdFury suggestion you could you a binary serializer if you do not need to "see" the data in the database.  XML serialization at least makes it readable

Comment: Binary serialization was my first try, actually - however I have had no success with getting the structure to serialize as binary.

Comment: I am concerned about the size if I go with keeping it in XML. Is 19 kb considered too big for an xml field?

Comment: Yes.  Looking at my ten largest tables in terms of data space, not rows, it looks like the largest is 1.05 kb per row.

Comment: Alright, this helps a bit. I know that I need to keep the usage of something like this extremely limited.

Answer (score 2):

Not an experienced DBA, but I would store the serialized data in a BLOB field in the database. Database backups do no good if the files your data is depending on go away or vice versa. I think it would simplify things to just keep it all together. And the blob works fine since the data you are storing does not need to be queried.

Comment: How would that work with the gzip compression? Or would I need to forego compression in favor of storing it like that?

Comment: @Ciel - not sure what you are using the do the compression, but as long as you can get a byte array, you can store it in the BLOB. So I imagine you can insert it into the table gzipped. I know the .NET framework has support for a stream that will do zip compression, but I've never used it. But based on the fact that it is a stream, you can get a byte array pretty easily from that.

Comment: @Ciel, @NerdFury - I've used the GZip stream class in .Net to store binary data in an Oracle database. The first trick is wrap the streams - so you have a backing MemoryStream, and the GZip stream goes over that, etc. The trick is you have to `.Flush()` *and* `.Close()` the GZip stream to get it to write the end of the stream. Once you do that, use the `.ToArray()` method of the underlying MemoryStream to get the compressed bits for the BLOB column. Decompressing is just doing that in reverse :)